# Windows: creating a shortcut to a non-exist drive doesn't allow long folder and filenames

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut, long-filenames

I'm trying to use PowerShell to create a shortcut that targets a file on a mapped drive. This script will be running *before* the drive is actually mapped, though. Here's the code:

```
$Shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut("$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Test.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "X:\Folder With Spaces\This is a long filename.txt"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Because the "X" drive doesn't exist yet, this is what the shortcut's "Target" field ends up saying:

Windows XP: X:\Folder_W\This_is_.txt

Windows 7: X:\Folder_With_Spaces\This_is_a_long_filename.txt

Both operating systems remove the surrounding double quotes and convert the spaces into underscores. Windows XP also truncates the folder and filenames to 8 characters.

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can get around it not checking the TargetPath.

I would suggest using the UNC path for the target so it does not depend on the drive being mapped.